# plot matplotlib plot (regression of medians) and pandas boxplot on the same chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I would like to plot a boxplot (pandas) and the regression of the medians on the same axes. Unfortunately, it does not work as expected. Neither

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=1)
data.boxplot(xxx, ax=ax)
ax.plot(xreg, yreg)
```

nor

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=1)
bplot = data.boxplot(xxx, ax=ax)
bplot.plot(xreg, yreg)
```

seems to work. [image]

The last approach seems to work slighty better The x does not fit together. Any ideas what might be the reason and how to get the same scale ob both axis ?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=1)
ax1 = ax.twiny()
bplot = data.boxplot(xxx, ax=ax)
ax1.plot(xreg, yreg)
```

[image]

The reason is probably the scaling of the axis:

```
ax.get_xlim()
(0.5, 4.5)

ax1.get_xlim()
(-4.0, 84.0)
```

If I just plot the regression and the medians without the boxplot, everything works fine:

[image]

Comment: what's wrong with them? it's impossible to understand you problem without knowing what you expect? maybe your data/result are wrong

Comment: edited the question in order to show how the data should look like. I will try to make a working example with toy data

Comment: So, where is the [mcve]?

Comment: I have to do other stuff too. I will have time in the evening (CET)

Comment: Oh, wow. I appreciate that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By looking at the [documentation of `plt.boxplot`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot), we find that the boxes are located by default at indexing positions 0,1,2,.. . The axes limits for N boxes are thus [-0.5, N+0.5].

The documentation tells us as well that the **locations of the boxes can be changed using the `positions` argument**.

Using this argument, we can position the boxes at any place along the x axis, and might then want to adapt their width, if their separation becomes very large or small.

Complete example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,70)
f = lambda x: 6*np.exp(-x/50.)

pos = [10, 40, 48, 64]
a = np.empty((100,len(pos)))
for i, p in enumerate(pos):
    a[:,i] = np.random.normal(loc=f(p), size=a.shape[0])

plt.boxplot(a, positions=pos, widths=5)
plt.plot(x, f(x))
plt.xlim(0,70)

plt.show()
```

[image]